# How to use fake object in javascript during development and avoid CORS error

Tags: javascript, cors

In a web page I load from a REST API some data to display in the page.
But during developing with Visual Studio Code and Live Server I have CORS errors because I'm trying to get data from the production source.
How can I develop and avoid this error?
Thanks!

Comment: TL;DR you can't, unless the production server returns the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as `*`, you will need a test server for this.

Comment: Just setup a test server : )

Comment: There are browser plugins for that. I'm using Moesif Origin & CORS changer for Chrome. It's an example. I tried a few and this one is the one least disruptive to me (many Google related things don't work when it's turned on, so it has to be easy to switch off.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not savvy in js. There is no way to define conditional execution or similar?

Comment: @robyg72 It's not a JS restriction per se, it's a browser thing.

Comment: @AyushGupta thanks. But when in test I will have a different URL. There is a best pratice to follow?

Comment: We handle these situations using env files, in the dev server, our app reads the dev configs and returns the url mentioned there is the CORS header. In prod, the prod configs are read and the URL mentioned there is sent in the CORS header

Comment: You either can use a browser extension or setup a server as a proxy.
With the server the flow will be like:

local frontend --> local proxy server --> prod server.
If you are gonna use the server, note that your endpoints must be different. e.g: if you prod domain is domain.com, your local proxy server should be local.domain.com. So instead of calling domain.com/api/posts you call local.domain.com/api/posts

That way you avoid the Access-Control-Allow-Origin browser control.

I guess the browser plugin is the easier way to go for you.

Answer (score 3):

If this is just a problem during development - Depending on your browser there are extensions available to disable CORS.

If you are using chrome there is one called [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en).

There is a similar one for firefox, [Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/access-control-allow-origin/).